# Enviar SMS Con URL Acortada API Infobip PHP

Tags: php, api, sms

Hola buen dia a todos,

Requiero de su ayuda, estoy tratando de enviar un SMS atraves de PHP con la API de Infobip, y quiero acortar la URL. pero no me funciona, no se si me falta algo mas por agregar. El mensaje si sale, pero sin URL.

```
$InfomacionUrl = ',
    "urlOptions": {
        "shortenUrl": true,
        "trackClicks": true,
        "trackingUrl": "' . $UrlShort . '",
        "removeProtocol": true,
        "customDomain": false
    }';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD => "default",
    CURLOPT_URL => $CURLOPT_URL . '/sms/2/text/advanced',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{
                "messages":
                [
                    {"destinations":
                        [
                            {
                                "to": "' . $ToNumberSend . '"
                            }
                        ],
                        "from": "Pruebas",
                        "text": "Mensaje  enviado para usuario: "
                    }
                ]' . $InfomacionUrl . '
            }',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: App ' . $AuthorizationKey,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json'
    )
));
$Response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $Response;
```

Aqui configuro todo el codigo para el envio, y como indico anteriormente el SMS sale pero no sale ni se acorta la URL. En la documentacion de acortar URL de infobip esto es lo que sale para realizar el acortamiento, pero no sale si hay que hacer alguna configuracion adicional.

Comment: ¿Has depurado el valor de `$UrlShort`? La estructura que mandas en `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` es válida y conforme a lo que te pide la API?

Comment: La variable de la URL, se esta enviando como una URL normal, para que la API realice el acortamiento, y si se esta enviando correctamente los parametros CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ya que si sale el SMS y no sale error.

Comment: Me refiero a que verifiques si `$UrlShort` **es una URL válida realmente**. Por otra parte, ¿podrías poner un `var_dump($Response);` y decirnos qué muestra?

Comment: La url es valida, de hecho para efectos de pruebas toma esta URL de esta publicacion
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/612675/enviar-sms-con-url-acortada-api-infobip-php
pero no funciona, adicional juego con los otros dos parametros poniendolo en false para no hacer seguimiento a la URL pero aun asi no funciona, cuando realizo la ejecucion me envia el SMS pero sin URL y esto es lo que retorna

{"messages":[{"messageId":"4067323067484335257045","status":{"description":"Message sent to next instance","groupId":1,"groupName":"PENDING","id":26,"name":"PENDING_ACCEPTED"},"to":"57******"}]}

Comment: En la documentación dice que el acortador está activo en la API, pero pone ejemplos basados en la biblioteca cliente de PHP. No sé si al estar usando cURL sea necesario activar algo en la petición cURL.